# Word VBA error 4199 File not found for existing file, called from OneDrive document

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365

I have a macro to copy some styles from a reference dotx file in the Template folder into the file I am editing. It works well if the file is purely in my local drive, but I receive a File not found error, code 4199, if the file being edited sits (locally) in OneDrive (business). Here is the code; the not-found file is in variable tpl, which points to an existing and valid file. If I run the same macro on the same file, but this time the file sits purely in a local folder, then there is no error.

I looked for similar cases online, but this seems to be an obscure occurrence. Thanks for any help!

```
'--start
    Sub GetStylesfromTemplate_zToCStyleforReports()
    Dim i, max As Integer
    Dim Hdgs(11 + 1) As String
    Dim tpl As String 'Complete path to template file
    
    'Number of styles
    max = 2
    
    'List of styles
    Hdgs(1) = "TOC 1": Hdgs(2) = "TOC 2"
    
    ' Environmental var plus end of template path and file name
    tpl = Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Report-ToC-Style-Here.dotx"
    
    For i = 1 To max
        Application.OrganizerCopy _
            source:=tpl, _
            Destination:=ActiveDocument, Name:=Hdgs(i), Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles
    Next
        
    End Sub 
' -- End
```

Comment: Which line raises the error?

Comment: The line after the For, when it tries to access the template file
`source:=tpl, source...`

Comment: Are you running the VBA from a file in your local OneDrive sync folder? VBA must run locally, it can run from an online OneDrive location.

Comment: Yes, the file on which the macro is applied was opened from my sync folder. The file in `tpl` variable is in the local system (within `%APPDATA%` path).

Comment: Try adding the OneDrive sync folder as a Trusted Location. File>Options>Trust Center>Trust Center Settings>Trusted Locations.